# Import .txt file and use in markov model

Tags: python

I am using this code to generate random text :

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from itertools import ifilter
from random import choice, randrange

def pairwise(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    last = next(it)
    for curr in it:
        yield last, curr
        last = curr

valid = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ')
def valid_pair((last, curr)):
    return last in valid and curr in valid

def make_markov(text):
    markov = defaultdict(Counter)
    lowercased = (c.lower() for c in text)
    for p, q in ifilter(valid_pair, pairwise(lowercased)):
        markov[p][q] += 1
    return markov

def genrandom(model, n):
    curr = choice(list(model))
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield curr
        if curr not in model:   # handle case where there is no known successor
            curr = choice(list(model)) #i.e. letter appears for first time at end of text
        d = model[curr]
        target = randrange(sum(d.values()))
        cumulative = 0
        for curr, cnt in d.items():
            cumulative += cnt
            if cumulative > target:
                break

model = make_markov(**'the fox jumped over the fence'**)
print ''.join(genrandom(model, 280))
```

However, I would like to use a txt file as input instead of 'the fox jumped over the fence'
I have been trying with :

```
text=open('moby.txt','r+').read()
```

and then:

```
model = make_markov(text)
```

But it seems that I have something wrong, I'm not sure how to handle this.

Comment: We need the description of 'wrong' to help you. Any error message ?

Comment: @e-satis : yes, this is the error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/python/Documents/markov.py", line 45, in <module>
    print ''.join(genrandom(model, 280))
  File "/Users/python/Documents/markov.py", line 30, in genrandom
    curr = choice(list(model))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Have you tried to replace "if curr not in model:" with a "while curr not in model"? Line 30 in your script is the first or second occurrence of "curr = choice(list(model))"?

Comment: This error appears consistent with behavior if 'moby.txt' has less than two characters in it (model will return an empty dictionary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter `text` is supposed to be the entire contents of Moby Dick , passed in as a string? Try passing the location of the text file and use it as a handle to generate your string from `read()`

```
Def makemarcov(fileloc):
    with open(fileloc, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
    #proceed...
```

Im on my phone, otherwise id also include the `open()` statement within a `try` clause.

## EDIT

The `with` keyword (if Im not mistaken), uses the `yield` statement behind the scenes, opening the file using a generator. It uses less resources to read large files.

Comment: I don't see how this is fundamentally different than what the OP described or how it would address the error they're seeing.

Comment: If the OP passed in a python *command* to open a text file, the argument would evaluate to a string `open('moby.txt', 'r+').read()`, instead of a book.

Comment: So you're saying `text=open('moby.txt','r+').read()` followed by `model = make_markov(text)` (as the OP described) would result in a markov model based on the string `open('moby.txt', 'r+').read()`? Even if that was the case why would that string cause the failure they were seeing?

Comment: Well I can't honestly say since I'm unfamiliar with the inner details of `random.py`. I read the code, and everything seemed fairly straightforward, except for the handling of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file, read it in, use it. I'd use the `with` statement which will guarantee the file gets closed afterwards.

```
with open(my_file, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
model = make_markov(text)
```

For quick and dirty code you can do it all in one go.

```
model = make_markov(open(my_file, 'r').read())
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. `with` is a powerful tool, and it should be included in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and it worked...

```
Aux = open("c:/Codes/A.txt",'r')
mystring = []
for i in Aux:
    mystring += i 

model = make_markov(mystring)
```

the output is not "that" clear ;-)

(Have you read Chomsky about Markovian grammars?)

But probably you are not really handling the case where there is no known successor!

Comment: Creating strings by repeatedly appending to them is bad style (depending on the language it can be O(n^2) cost). If you really have to do this, then `mystring = ''.join(Aux)` is preferable, but here `mystring = Aux.read()` avoids breaking the file into lines only to join them back again.